# What building boosts Saka Horse Archers?

Tags: civilization-6

Are Saka Horse Archers boosted by a Barracks or a Stable?

Comment: Are you asking which one you should choose?

Comment: @Vemonus I think they are asking what I answered, what type of unit is the unique unit classified as that would determine what type of building you need in your encampments to boost their XP when producing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Saka Horse Archer](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Saka_Horse_Archer_(Civ6)) is a [ranged unit](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Units_(Civ6)#Ranged), not cavalry. This is noted in it's wiki page as I linked and it is also noted that the unit upgrades directly into the [field cannon](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Field_Cannon_(Civ6)), not another cavalry.

Although it is researched under Horseback Riding, and benefits from the "Make 1 Get 1" bonus of [Scythia](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Scythian_(Civ6)) for light cavalry and horse archer units, they do not actually require horses to build, and they are not actual cavalry units.

So to answer *your* question specifically, **you will need a [barracks](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Barracks_(Civ6)) to boost the units XP** since they are for melee and ranged units, and a [stable](http://civ6.gamepedia.com/Stable) is only used for cavalry units.